# Mouse I/O in assembly 68K

Tags: mouse, assembly

I had a problem with reading the position of mouse in screen in assembly 68K, what I have to do? I even read the the help of Easy68K, but I couldn't understand what it exactly says. I would be thankful if someone explains about IRQ levels and how to read the position of mouse when we click on screen.